# How do I concatenate a string within a loop with PowerShell?

Tags: string, loops, powershell, foreach, concatenation

The command

```
Get-VM | Where {$_.PowerState -eq "PoweredOn"} | Select Name,VMHost | Where {$_ -match "abc" -or $_ -match "def"} | foreach{$_.Name} | Out-File output.txt
```

writes a list to output.txt where only the column Name will be printed in the form:

```
a
b
c
...
```

Now what I want to achieve is to append `,xxx` to each line in some sort of loop, so that I get the following:

```
a,xxx
b,xxx
c,xxx
...
```

I tried to append the string, but this doesn't seem to work:

```
Get-VM | Where {$_.PowerState -eq "PoweredOn"} | Select Name,VMHost | Where {$_ -match "abc" -or $_ -match "def"} | foreach{$_.Name} | Out-File output.txt | Add-Content output.txt ",xxx"
```

I'm really not familiar with PowerShell, and I did not find a way to concatenate `,xxx`.

**In my case it is essential to do the concatenation within a loop, not with a file operation afterwards.**

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Instead of `foreach { $_.Name }`, write `foreach { "$($_.Name),xxx" }`